# Swift. How to get specific data from a snapshot from Firebase database

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

Okay I'm recieving a snapshot from my Firebase Database, this is my code and what I'm recieving:

```
rootRef.child("Battles").queryOrderedByChild("Player1").queryEqualToValue(CurrentFBID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in
    if (snap.value is NSNull) {
        print("none")
    } else {
        print(snap.value)
    }
})
```

Recieving:

> {
>
> "04361D33-AC99-4795-BB9A-0B0879882251" =
>
> {
>
> BattleUUID = "04361D33-AC99-4795-BB9A-0B0879882251";
>
> Player1 = 10210238266903604;
>
> Player2 = 12121212121212;
>
> Score = "0-0";
>
> Turn = 1;
>
> };
>
> }

My JSON tree:

```
{
  "Battles" : {
    "04361D33-AC99-4795-BB9A-0B0879882251" : {
      "BattleUUID" : "04361D33-AC99-4795-BB9A-0B0879882251",
      "Player1" : "10210238266903604",
      "Player2" : "12121212121212",
      "Score" : "0-0",
      "Turn" : "1"
    },
    "07261D43-GC59-4795-BB9A-0B0871635751" : {
      "BattleUUID" : "04361D33-AC99-4795-BB9A-0B0879882251",
      "Player1" : "1342536342535",
      "Player2" : "1524343564",
      "Score" : "3-1",
      "Turn" : "5"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I split that data so as an example:

```
let player1 = snap.Player1.value
let player2 = snap.Player2.value
let battleUUID = snap.BattleUUID.value
let score = snap.Score.value
let turn = snap.Turn.value
```

Comment: So what is your query ? You want only `player1` and `player2` data and not the rest ?

Comment: I just updated my question, sorry for my bad explanation. I want all of the data, but I want to split the data into different constants

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving all data at once. The `snap` contains `children` and each `child` belongs to a particular battle.
To get data corresponding to each child you have to iterate over `children` of `snap` as :

```
for item in snap.children {
    let player1 = item.value?["Player1"] as! String
    let player2 = item.value?["Player2"] as! String
    let battleUUID = item.value?["BattleUUID"] as! String
    let score = item.value?["Score"] as! String
    let turn = item.value?["Turn"] as! String
}
```

Comment: When I do that i returns an error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unrapping an Optional value

Comment: It is because one of your `property` is `nil` try to use `?` istead of `!`  like - `let player1 = item.value?["player1"] as? String`

Comment: Now it just returns "nil", not what it is supposed to do

Comment: Is it printing `nil` for all values (`player1`, `player2`, `battleUUID`, `score`, `turn` )?

Comment: Yes it is printing nil for every 5 values

Comment: If it is any help it says "cast from '[SKNode]?'  to unrelated type 'String' always fail

Comment: Check your key `case` , it should exactly match with the key you are providing like `Player1` (`P` is upperCase). Otherwise,  try checking whether the value is nil or not then assign : `if  item.value?["Player1"] != nil { let player1 = item.value?["player1"] as! String}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120270/discussion-between-triple-s-and-benja0906).